# Couldn't Hanashiro Anzu save Touno Kaoru pulling him out of the tunnel in "Natsu e no Tunnel, Sayonara no Deguchi"?

Tags: the-tunnel-to-summer

Recently, I watched the movie and I would like know if the years of separation couldn't be avoided.

As shown in the experiments they both conducted at the very beginning, time inside the tunnel passes incredibly slower from the perspective of whom is outside. So, if she entered the cave, she would see the protagonist still at the entrance, moving slowly. From his perspective, he would see her appearing to him at the speed of light.

[image]

This way, wasn't it perfectly possible to save him, going after him and pull him out of the tunnel? Why didn't she go after him?